# macOS, Swift 3: How to get data back after segue?

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, segue, transfer

**For example:** I have two `UIViewController`s. The first has a button and a `NSTextField`, and the second has a `NSTextField` only.

When I click the button on the first controller — the second controller shows as popover window.

Making a transfer of some data from first controller to second is not big deal — I use a segue. But what I should to do to transfer data back — from the popover window to main window? 
**For example:** we open the popover window, type some text in `NSTextField`, and I want to get this text in the `NSTextField` of the first `ViewController`.

I can't find the answer :-(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/434/passing-data-between-view-controllers/2520/using-the-delegate-pattern-passing-data-back#t=201611080745298224365 (it's in the iOS tag, but it works on macOS, too)

Comment: You can use an unwindSegue method if your view controllers are in a navigation controller, or you can use a protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In macOS it's pretty easy if you are using storyboard and segues.

`NSViewController` has a property `presenting` which contains a reference to the parent view controller.

Obtain the reference, call a method in the parent view controller to pass the data and dismiss the child view controller.

```
let firstViewController = presenting as! FirstViewController
firstViewController.passDataBack(data)
self.dismiss(self)
```

Comment: Thanks! Other guy told me that the "right" way is to use delegates. That video is pretty good for understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhqXUi1SF4s

Comment: Youtube hasn't got a seal of quality. Anybody can upload stuff ;-)